# Where do my files from Source Control reside in Linux for TeamCity

Tags: svn, ubuntu, teamcity

I want to know where do the files get checked out to when I specify the source control in TeamCity. I googled but cannot find which path it is being checked out to. I searched inside the .BuildServer directory inside my home folder but no luck. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Windows box, checkouts get put into the `work` directory inside the build agent. I'm making the assumption that it will be same on linux. The [TeamCity docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Agent+Work+Directory) seem to confirm this.

The checkout directories' names resemble hashes. Look in the `directory.map` file for a mapping of which directory represents which build configuration.

---

To answer your question in the comment:

To do this, you could add a build step that does the modification (using some custom logic that you would have to create) as the first step of the build. I would recommend changing your tests so that they work the same way as when cleanly checked-out from source control. This will ensure that your tests are repeatable in a consistent manner. It might be more work, but it will pay off in the longer term, especially if your tests fail in TeamCity but not on your machine - a difficult situation to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now that you're here, I have one more doubt. I am confident that my tests will fail if I use my source control as is. I want to make some modifications to the checkedout files. How to do that?

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response. But i find it a bit hard to adapt to this (since I have used cruisecontrol.rb before). There, it does a "svn up" on the checkedout directory so it would be easy for me to just go and modify certain files (mostly configuration files). But here, it seems to check out the entire source everytime. I love the interface of Team City but if I am able to fix this one problem, it would be lovely!!!

Comment: @Bragboy: From memory, I think there may be an option to do what you want (in the VCS tab there is a set of radio buttons), but it will not be very robust. As soon as TeamCity does a clean of the checkout, you will lose the changes you have made. You will also have to make the changes on each agent.